# Comparing machine learning algorithms on features selected by a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, feature-selection

I'm reading a paper where they use a neural network to select 9 features from tabular input data with 20 features. And then, this is what feels weird to me, they run several machine learning algorithms (logistic regression, k-nearest neighbor, naive bayes, decions tree, tree bagger, etc.) with these 9 features to compare the performance of the algorithms to the performance of the neural network. Does this step make any sense, and if yes, why?

[Citation:
Korani, Walid, et al. "Machine learning as an effective method for identifying true single nucleotide polymorphisms in polyploid plants." The plant genome 12.1 (2019): 180023.](https://acsess.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.3835/plantgenome2018.05.0023)

Comment: Can you please give a citation for the paper (not just a link, but the full citation from Google Scholar or something similar)? Out of context, I share your skepticism. After all, why should the features important to a nonlinear model like a neural network be important to a generalized linear model like logistic regression? However, if they are taking the last hidden layer before the output layer, then this makes more sense. (In many way, neural networks have a layer or layers of feature extraction before fitting a generalized linear model to the extracted features.)

Comment: Do the authors have their code available, perhaps on GitHub? The "methods" section makes no mention of how the neural networks are used to do feature extraction, and the mention in the "discussion" section mentions but does not expand on using neural networks for feature selection.

Comment: https://github.com/w-korani/SNP-ML